# NSXMLParser is not parsing HTML tags

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

I am trying to parse XML which is as follows.

```
<xml>
<item>
<title>
21/2/2014 13:18:22
</title>
<time>
2014-02-21 02:49:03
</time>
<message>
<strong>
abcd</strong><br /><br /><em>abcd</em><br /><br /><u>abcd</u><br /><br /><br />  
</message>
</item>
<item>
<title>
21/2/2014 12:9:40
</title>
<time>
2014-02-21 01:57:28
</time>
<message>
100
</message>
</item>
</xml>
```

I am parsing using the normal parsing procedure

**My Parser.h**

```
#import "XMLData.h"
@interface XMLParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{    
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSMutableArray  *datas;
    NSXMLParser     *parser;
    XMLData     *recentEnquiry;
}
@property (readonly, retain) NSMutableArray *datas;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString;
```

**My Parser.m**

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser
@synthesize datas;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    datas          = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(@"Data is %@",data);
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        recentEnquiry = [XMLData alloc];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        recentEnquiry.title = currentNodeContent;

    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"time"])
    {
        recentEnquiry.time = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"message"])
    {
        recentEnquiry.message = currentNodeContent;
        [datas addObject:recentEnquiry];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

@end
```

However for the first item I just get ">" as the message where I should get the text embedded in html tags. I read about other parsing technique knowing that NSXMParser's drawback however I just want the text. I will convert and split the html by myself.

NB: I am getting the desired texts with html tags in foundCharacters method but they come in a loop.

Comment: sorry, seems like it's not HTML

Comment: @Injectios please look at the message node of the first item. You will see the html tags.

Comment: Then what should I do to parse these tags. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Daij-Djan It might be, syntactically well-formed, but not semantically. He probably meant everything in between `<message>` and `</message>` to be a single value that included HTML.

Comment: @Rob Thats correct but these things work out when I parse the normal text. What all things I should do in foundCharacters.

Comment: @Saty BTW, don't forget to also call `init` after calling `alloc` of your `XMLData` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. The XML is not well-designed: The contents of your `message` element should encode the HTML. One approach is to replace `<`, `>`, and `&` with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`:

   ```
   <xml>
   <item>
   <title>
   21/2/2014 13:18:22
   </title>
   <time>
   2014-02-21 02:49:03
   </time>
   <message>
   &lt;strong&gt;
   abcd&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;em&gt;abcd&lt;/em&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;u&gt;abcd&lt;/u&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;  
   </message>
   </item>
   <item>
   <title>
   21/2/2014 12:9:40
   </title>
   <time>
   2014-02-21 01:57:28
   </time>
   <message>
   100
   </message>
   </item>
   </xml>
   ```

   Or, as described by Daij-Djan, you can use `CDATA` (opened with `<![CDATA[` and terminated with `]]>`):

   ```
   <xml>
   <item>
   <title>
   21/2/2014 13:18:22
   </title>
   <time>
   2014-02-21 02:49:03
   </time>
   <message>
   <![CDATA[
   <strong>
   abcd</strong><br /><br /><em>abcd</em><br /><br /><u>abcd</u><br /><br /><br />  
   ]]>
   </message>
   </item>
   <item>
   <title>
   21/2/2014 12:9:40
   </title>
   <time>
   2014-02-21 01:57:28
   </time>
   <message>
   100
   </message>
   </item>
   </xml>
   ```

   For more information about handling the reserved characters of `<`, `>` and `&` in your XML, see section [2.4 Character Data and Markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax), of the XML specification.
2. Your `foundCharacters` incorrectly assumes that the contents of a field will always be returned by a single call to that method. That's not a valid assumption. You should always assume it may take multiple calls to `foundCharacters` to return the whole value. Thus, instantiate the `currentNodeElement` in `didStartElement`, append to it in `foundCharacters`, and save and reset it in `didEndElement`. Thus you may want something like:

   ```
   - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
   {
       if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
       {
           recentEnquiry = [[XMLData alloc] init];
       }
       else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"] || [elementname isEqualToString:@"time"] || [elementname isEqualToString:@"message"])
       {
           currentNodeContent = [NSMutableString string];
       }
   }

   - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   {
       if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
       {
           recentEnquiry.title = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
       }
       else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"time"])
       {
           recentEnquiry.time = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
       }
       else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"message"])
       {
           recentEnquiry.message = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
       }
       else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
       {
           [datas addObject:recentEnquiry];
       }

       currentNodeContent = nil;
   }

   - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
   {
       [currentNodeContent appendString:string]; // do not trim whitespace here
   }
   ```

   Clearly, `currentNodeContent` should be defined as a `NSMutableString`, not just a `NSString`.